# SQL Select query to pick the field value which has more than one empty space?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my LastName Column, I have either one name or two names. In some records, I have more than one empty space between the two names.

I will have to select the records which has more than one empty space in the field name.

```
declare @nam nvarchar(4000)
declare @nam1 nvarchar(4000)

set @nam = 'sam' + ' ' + 'Dev'
set @nam1 = 'ed' + ' ' +  ' ' + 'Dev'
```

In the sample query, i expect the output value should be @nam1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `LEN` and `REPLACE` to replace the spaces from string and then get `original length - replaced length` and then check that in `WHERE` clause,

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    mytTable
WHERE 
    LEN(LastName)-LEN(REPLACE(LastName, ' ', '')) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you @coderofcode, This blindly fixes the issue. I need to generate a report on list of names / records impacted. Before i fix the issue